# React-tagsinput not allowing me to pasteSplit input

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, paste

I am trying to achieve the following result:

When user copy-pastes input to TagsInput object from react-tagsinput package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tagsinput) the input will split all values separated by any space-like character (tab, etc.) as separate values. So for example, I copy paste a list of names from Excel and they appear in the inputfield as separate tags.

The library clearly shows to pasteSplit function, which is mentioned there in the link. I us it as follows:

```
  <TagsInput pasteSplit={this.pasteSplit} value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.handleChangeInList} />
```

I did logs in the pasteSplit function (which is exactly as in the example from the package link), I did logs in the node_module itself, however, it seems as if none of these ever activate (neither the constructor of the node module!). However, the whole TagsInput object works properly, adds tags, display them, etc, they are just all added on enter, and I want to add columns from excel.

Where could be the problem with it? Is there other way to solve it?

Thank you in Advance,

Grzegorz

Comment: According to the source code pasteSplit doesn't modify input value, it just returns an array made from source string. So you should call it as a function and use returned value

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov but it says to use it as props for TagsInput

Comment: Sorry, probably I've missed something. So you're redefining pasteSplit function, as it shown in example? Could provide full code please?

Comment: As in the link to the package, I am copy pasting the same function

Answer (score 0):

I've checked source one more time. `pasteSplit` called internally if `addOnPaste` attribute is enabled.

So your code should look like this:

```
  <TagsInput pasteSplit={this.pasteSplit} value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.handleChangeInList} addOnPaste />
```